# Trying to prove the Stirling approximation using concavity for $x\geq 1$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, convex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the Stirling approximation.

##### Problem:

Let $x\geq 1$ then we have :

$${\displaystyle \Gamma (x)={\sqrt {\frac {2\pi }{x}}}\,{\left({\frac {x}{e}}\right)}^{x}\left(1+O\left({\frac {1}{x}}\right)\right).}$$

##### First fact:

For $x\ge 1$ define:

$$f(x)=(x!)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Then:

$$f''(x)<0$$

My sketch of proof of the Fact 1:

We need to show for $x,a\geq 1 $:

$$\left(\left(\frac{a+x}{2}\right)!\right)^{\frac{2}{x+a}}-\left(x!\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}-\left(a!\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}\ge 0$$

Setting $a^{-1}=y,x^{-1}=z$ we need to show for $0<y,z\leq 1$ :

$$\left(\left(\frac{y^{-1}+z^{-1}}{2}\right)!\right)^{\frac{2}{y^{-1}+z^{-1}}}-\left(z^{-1}!\right)^{z}-\left(y^{-1}!\right)^{y}\ge 0$$

We have the two inequalities for $y\ge z$:

$$\left(z^{-1}!\right)^{z}\geq\left(y^{-1}!\right)^{y}$$

$$\left(\left(\frac{y^{-1}+z^{-1}}{2}\right)!\right)^{\frac{-2}{y^{-1}+z^{-1}}}-\left(z^{-1}!\right)^{-z}\leq 0$$

And for $0<y,z\leq 1$:

$$\left(\left(\frac{y^{-1}+z^{-1}}{2}\right)!\right)^{\frac{-4}{y^{-1}+z^{-1}}}-\left(y^{-1}!\right)^{-y}\left(z^{-1}!\right)^{-z}\leq 0$$

These inequalities comes first from the fact that $f(x)$ is increasing and the concavity of $(\ln(f(x))$

So using Karamata's inequality on the convexity of exponential we have shown the concavity of $f(x)$

Now we can squeeze the function $f(x)$ with a tangent and a slope with a gap equal to one .

Now I don't know how to appear the $\sqrt{2\pi}$

Some explanation :

Using concavity we have for $x\in[n,n+1]$ and $n\geq 1$ a natural number :

$$\left(\left(f\left(n+1\right)-f\left(n\right)\right)\left(x-n-1\right)+f\left(n+1\right)\right)^{x}\le x!\le\left(f'\left(n\right)\left(x-n\right)+f\left(n\right)\right)^{x}$$

So now we need a bound for $f'(x)$ . Numerical evidence says that for $x\geq 1$ it seems we have

$$\frac{1}{e}< f'(x)< \frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{5.5x}$$

On the other hand  we can use the Stirling approximation in the discrete case to squeeze $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ see the wiki page .

##### Question:

> How to achieve my sketch of proof?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how the fact that a function is concave should lead to an asymptotic approximation?

Comment: @MartinR as $x\to \infty $ we have $f''(x)\to 0$ so the accuracy increases as well

Comment: @XanderHanderson Thanks for use your time for me and thanks for the edit .

Comment: $f$ is concave iff $f\left(\frac{a+x}{2}\right) \ge \frac 12 \left(f(a) + f(x) \right)$. The factor $\frac 12$ seems to be missing in your $$\left(\left(\frac{a+x}{2}\right)!\right)^{\frac{2}{x+a}}-\left(x!\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}-\left(a!\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}\ge 0$$